# How can I convert part of code to Twig format?

Tags: php, twig

I need convert this code to Twig format for Opencart3. But no success. Any idea?

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
<?php
    $cm_count = 0;
    $cm_count = count($cannedmessages);
    if ($cm_count == 0) { ?>
        Use the button to setup a new canned message
    <?php } else { ?>                       
    <select name="cannedmessage" id="cannedmessage" class="form-control">
        <option></option>
        <?php foreach ($cannedmessages as $cannedmessage) {
            if( $cannedmessage['status']==1) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cannedmessage['description']; ?>"><?php echo $cannedmessage['title']; ?></option>
            <?php } 
        } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

I try this with converter on https://php2twig.com/index.php but with error..

```
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    cm_count 0
    cm_count count(cannedmessages)
    {% if cm_count is 0 %}
       Use the button to setup a new canned message
    {% else %}
        <select name="cannedmessage" id="cannedmessage" class="form-control">
      <option></option>
      {% for cannedmessage in cannedmessages %}
      {% if cannedmessage.status is 1 %}
          <option value="{{ cannedmessage.description }}">{{ cannedmessage.title }}</option>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      </select>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
```

I fight with creating "Canned message" in Opencart 3. But I'm losing the battle...

Comment: What problem are you having specifically? Note that code writing or code conversion requests are off-topic here, so you need to show what small problem you are getting stuck on.

Comment: I had a badly redone code to the twig format. This part:  <code> "cm_count 0
    cm_count count(cannedmessages)
    {% if cm_count is 0 %}" </code>    D. Dimitrioglo helped me well. Its adjustment worked for me. Thanks for trying to help. I appreciate that. Ondra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check if your `cannedmessage` has `title` property, and try this:

```
{% if cannedmessages|length > 0 %}
    <select name="cannedmessage" id="cannedmessage" class="form-control">
        <option></option>
        {% for cannedmessage in cannedmessages %}
            {% if cannedmessage.status == 1 %}
                <option value="{{ cannedmessage.description }}">{{ cannedmessage.title }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% else %}
    Use the button to setup a new canned message
{% endif %}
```